# Action Bar and Activity Handling in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, android-actionbar, xamarin.android, android-theme

I have two questions:

I want to change the Action Bar color. Right now I'm using the default theme for the application. How can I do this?

The next question is: How can I show some specific activities when the application is running for the very first time on device after installation? I don't want to show them again after that.

Answer (score 1):

1) 
You can change the color exactly like in an native android app.
http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

Here is a xamarin related tutorial: https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-material-design-v7-appcompat/

2) You could use the [Settings Plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Settings/) and then read a boolean value like

```cs
var settings = CrossSettings.Current;
var shownFirstLaunch = settings.GetValueOrDefault<bool>("FirstLaunchShown", false);
if(shownFirstLaunch) {
    // show Mainactivity
}
else {
    settings.AddOrUpdateValue<bool>("FirstLaunchShown", true);
    // show first launch activity
}
```